# I want to run .ps1 file through a .bat file

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run this PowerShell code through Task Scheduler as I want to run this code 24*7. Task Scheduler is not runnin .ps1 file.  So I want to run a .bat file from Task Scheduler which will invoke this PowerShell file.

Following is my PowerShell code (filename is Watch.ps1):

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "D:\MigrationWorkflow\UAT"
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Invoke-Expression 'MASysMgr.exe -w MigrationUAT.smw -f "D:\MigrationWorkflow\UAT\ParameterUat.smp" -l WorkflowResults.log -showoutput' }

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler can run PowerShell scripts just fine, but you need to put `powershell.exe` as the program to execute, and `-File "C:\path\to\watch.ps1"` as the parameters for the program.

In your case you should also add the parameter `-NoExit`, so that PowerShell doesn't terminate, and remove the `while` loop from your script (or at least set the sleep time to a couple hundred milliseconds, so that the system can do other things in the meantime).